# Как рисовать в фотошопе 8-битные картинки?

Tags: графика, photoshop

Мне нужно нарисовать декорацию для 8-битной игры, но все картинки получаются с глубиной цвета 32 бита. Пробовал менять разные настройки в фотошопе (изображение- режим- 8бит/канал) но картинки все равно 32-битные.

[image: вот сама фотография, скачав которою можно усидеть в свойствах глубину цвета 32]

Comment: Ну, 8 бит на канал, красный-зелёный-синий-альфа это в сумме как раз 32 бита

Comment: А режим нужно выбирать «Таблица цветов», она как раз восьмибитная

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Фотошоп разный бывает. Я распишу для Adobe Photoshop CC 2018. Итак, по шагам...

1. Создаем сперва новую картинку заданной геометрии. `Файл` → `Создать`, там выбираем `Цветовой режим RGB 8бит`
2. После создания новой картинки - сразу же меняем цветовой режим. `Изображение` → `Режим` → `Индексированные цвета`. В открывшемся диалоге меняем `Палитра`, допустим на *Системная (Windows)* или *Равномерная* (про использование преобразования в индексированные цвета - [подробнее можно почитать тут](https://helpx.adobe.com/ru/photoshop-elements/using/using-image-modes-color-tables.html)):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

3. Начинайте рисовать. При выборе цвета обращайте внимание, что не все цвета на цветовом кубе доступны (из-за выбранной битности), это можно увидеть в предупреждении и предложении ближайшего возможного цвета:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

4. При сохранении нарисованного файла `Файл` → `Сохранить как...` смело выбирайте формат `GIF`. Этот формат как раз представляет 8-битную картинку. Можно выбрать и формат `BMP`, но тогда нужно будет дополнительно указать `Глубина` `8-бит`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Бинго!